# Task Scheduler: How to schedule a task to execute at login

Tags: c++, winapi, scheduled-tasks

I am working with the Windows Task Scheduler using C++ Win32 - see MSDN link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383614(v=VS.85).aspx. I know that to schedule a task at a specific time TASK_TRIGGER_TIME, TASK_TRIGGER_DAILY, MONTHLY etc. I dont need to be a admin or ask for elevated permissions.

I am getting errors on saving my login & boot tasks & I am not sure why?

**Do I need admin privileges or elevated rights to schedule a task to execute when I login or when my laptop starts (TASK_TRIGGER_LOGON, TASK_TRIGGER_BOOT)?**

Comment: "I am getting errors on saving my login & boot tasks & I am not sure why?" What do the errors say?

Answer (score 1):

Only a member of the Administrators group can create a task with a boot trigger. The documentation clearly states so, check the **[link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa380603%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)**

As for the Logon trigger, [**here**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa381911%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is an example on MSDN, which might help you see what you are missing.